# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} g \left(\frac{x^4 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2}\right)$ where $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{g(z)}{z}=2.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

This limit seems different to me than all the other multi variable limits already asked on this site.

> Let $g \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be such that $$ \lim_{z\to
>  0}\frac{g(z)}{z}=2. $$
>   Evaluate if the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} g \left(\frac{x^4 +
>  y^4}{x^2 + y^2}\right)$$ exists, and if it does, determine it.

I tried to approach the limit with for example $x=0$, $y=0$ etcetera, but I'm not even sure where for example $g(x^2)$ so $g(z)$ goes to. 
Also, polar coordinates does not seem the way to go here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$g(z)=\left(\frac{g(z)}{z}\right)z.$$

Comment: A nice hint.  +1.

Comment: This hint did it, of course you can just use the limit theorems to have $\lim_{z \to 0} g(z)$ go to $2 \cdot 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Start by convincing yourself that

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x^4 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2} = 0$$

Now once this is true, consider the following: When $z$ is very small,

$$\frac{g(z)}{z} \approx 2$$

This is a problem unless $\lim_{z \to 0} g(z)$ exists and is a very particular number. Think about what this number ought to be.

> The number is zero.

Comment: This is some nice way of looking at it, it does help coming up with a hint like David's.